# Can the integer once converted to String using toString() method be reconverted back to Integer?

Tags: java

```
public class ArrayManipulations {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String name = num.toString();
        System.out.println(name); // want to convert this back to int 
        System.out.println(num.getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(num.hashCode()));
}

}
```

Now i want to convert the name back to integer.
is it possible???

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(name);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Yes you can**

Return an **Object** `Integer` :

```
Integer var = Integer.valueOf("0");
```

> This method returns the relevant **Number Object** holding the
>   value of the argument passed. The argument can be a primitive data
>   type, String, etc.

Return a **primitive** `int` :

```
int var = Integer.parseInt("0");
```

> This method is used to get the **primitive data** type of a certain
>   String. parseXxx() is a static method and can have one argument or
>   two.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert String to int, you use:

```
int intNum = Integer.parseInt(name); //name is variable that you want to change back to int
```

Answer (score 0):

The Integer class provides the following method for this task:

```
Integer.parseInt(String s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(3));
```

should do the trick. 
More in the  [Java Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-int-).